# UITableView & UICollectionView showing same data in 2 different situations

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a scenario in which I require to display some data in `UITableView` when user clicks on a particular `UIButton` and display the same data in `UICollectionView` when clicked on another `UIbutton` . But in the same view controller .

First when table view is selected we are going for data in table view -
it would show data in table view format

Second when collection view button is clicked we are going for displaying data in collection view.

I think we can achieve this by the following ways -

1)**Creating 2 views in scene dock** one having table view and the other having collection view and using them in our code.

2)**Creating 2 .xib files** of UIView class having TableView & CollectionView and loading them on selection of particular button.

So how could I achieve this functionality? Please suggest some ways which could be quite reliable in such cases and if possible share any source codes or links or give detailed explanation which could help iOS novices like me.

Comment: I think bette way you take 2 custom cell one for grid view second for list view then. when click on grid then load grid cell and when click list then load list cell.

Comment: Use collection view.

Comment: May be 2nd is better

Comment: @mitulmarsonia  How to do that? Ya that is my point. How to load 2 views one having UITableView & other having UICollectionView. I can't get you. Please post an answer with a bit detailed steps.It would be quite helpful.

Comment: Yes you are right @G.Abhisek

Comment: Create two class one with UITableView baseClass and another with UICollectionView baseClass and load it in your viewController.

Comment: @MehulSojitra I appreciate your comment. Can you post a detailed explanatory answer So that readers of this question as well as me can get your suggestion perfectly. A bit more descriptive steps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use UIPageViewController. Just remember to disable scrolling of pageviewcontroller.

Comment: What you are suggesting is UIPageViewController with multiple view controller as its content or what . Because the content view controller can at a Time use only one view in it either UITableView or UICollectionView.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like to make custom view container. 
Google with keywords `iOS custom container`, there are many resources.

- [Custom container view controller transitions](https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/custom-container-view-controller-transitions/)
- [Container View controller quick start](https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Container-View-Controllers-Quickstart)
- [Apple document, about custom container](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)

Comment: Container view controller is a good option but I don't want to use container view as I do have unlimited number of categorical items as shown in screenshot,it is only for one category e.g - For one type of items. There are numerous number of categories in the e-commerce. And for each category loading two view controllers,I don't think it would be advisable.

Comment: They can be implemented by `ONE` data source. But `tableView` and `collectionView` share the same data source object. There are many options for this problem, and custom container is in order to adjust more `custom` UI behaviors.

Comment: Ya but you understand that it might make my situation more inconvenient & can also affect the user experience. And what about scene docks?

Comment: It depends on how many custom UI designs in this scene. Maybe `UITabBarController` is good enough. I will use only `ONE` data source for tableView and collectionView. Let complex business logic be wrapped in the data source. And the designs of  `tableView` and `collectionView` are as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add both the UItableView and UICollectionView in the same view and make one of them hidden in each state. So by default the first button is selected where the collectionView will be hidden. When user taps on the second button you can hide the table view and unhide the collection view. You can also add animation for transitioning two state to make it look good.

Comment: But adding 2 views overlapping on another will make adding constraints and layouts to them difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If we simply think about this problem then we can use only one collectionView with two different kind of Layouts and cellViews of different sizes. But I am not sure, how much will be the complexity with Aujtolayout (if you using).

Answer (score 0):

First create two class file with `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` baseClass for more detail see below screenshot.
[image]

And add datasource and delegate method for both class in implementation file.

Now add following code in .h(interface) file where you want to show table/collection view.

```
#import "collectionData.h"
#import "tableData.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    collectionData *collectionObj;
    tableData *tableObj;

    IBOutlet UIView *viewData;
}

@end
```

And in .m(implementation) file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *arrCollection = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"collectionData" owner:self options:nil];
    collectionObj = (collectionData *)[arrCollection objectAtIndex:0];


    NSArray *arrTable = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"tableData" owner:self options:nil];
    tableObj = (tableData *)[arrTable objectAtIndex:0];

    [self displayView:tableObj];

}

- (IBAction)btnTableClick:(id)sender {
    [self displayView:tableObj];
}

- (IBAction)btnCollectionClick:(id)sender {
    [self displayView:collectionObj];
}

- (void)displayView: (UIView *)viewObj {
    for(UIView *view in viewData.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    [viewData addSubview:viewObj];
}
```

**Note that its not everything yet that you want it's only basic idea.**

Answer (score 0):

I would personally suggest any one facing such type of situation to go for Scene Dock which many don't care to use. It requires quite less coding and is very easy. I think it can be considered as an alternative for .xib .

I followed some details about scene dock in the link - http://www.raywenderlich.com/115697/ios-9-storyboards-tutorial-whats-new-in-storyboards

Add a table view and a collection view in the scene dock of your view controller and go for the coding. Here is an example of hoe it can be done.

Main story board -

[image]

Here goes the coding with all explannations -

```
  import UIKit

class CategoriesViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate
{




    var mainarray : NSMutableArray!
    var cararray : NSMutableArray!
    var bikearray : NSMutableArray!




    @IBOutlet var TableVieww: UITableView!//table view outlet in scene dock

    @IBOutlet var collctnvieww: UICollectionView!//scene dock collection view outlet
    @IBOutlet weak var rqdview: UIView!// view on which you would be adding the collection/table view


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         cararray = ["audii","duster"]
         bikearray = ["honda","bajaj"]

        TableVieww.dataSource = self
        TableVieww.delegate = self

        collctnvieww.delegate = self
        collctnvieww.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    @IBAction func Car(sender: AnyObject)//outlet of car button
    {
        mainarray = cararray as NSMutableArray
        self.TableVieww.reloadData()
        self.collctnvieww.reloadData()
    }



    @IBAction func bike(sender: AnyObject)//outlet of bike button
    {
        mainarray = bikearray as NSMutableArray
        self.TableVieww.reloadData()
        self.collctnvieww.reloadData()
    }




    @IBAction func showcllctnview(sender: AnyObject)//when you want to show collection view for cars/bikes
    {

        print("collection view called")
        collctnvieww.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, rqdview.frame.width, rqdview.frame.height)//you change the frame size of your views as per your requirement.


        self.rqdview.addSubview(collctnvieww)
    }



    @IBAction func showtableview(sender: AnyObject)//when you want to show table view for cars/bikes

    {
        print("table view called")
        TableVieww.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, rqdview.frame.width, rqdview.frame.height)

        self.rqdview.addSubview(TableVieww)
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return mainarray.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = TableVieww.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellreuse", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel!.text = mainarray[indexPath.row] as? String

        return cell

    }

//coding for collection view
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return mainarray.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collctnvieww.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("collectioncell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CategoriesCollectionViewCell

        cell.nmlbl.text = mainarray[indexPath.row] as? String
        return cell

    }





    }
```

But still I think the code can be shortened if I can use only one data source for table view and collection view. If any one can suggest some tips, it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial view controller can house the buttons and a "[Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)" that will segue between a `UITableViewController` and a `UICollectionViewController` based on the button that was pressed. When a button is tapped, the initial view controller will pass along the product data and make itself the child view controller's delegate.

When a cell is selected in either of your child view controllers, they can call methods on the delegate (your initial view controller) and it can act accordingly.

To pass data into whatever child view controller you want to display first (e.g. the `UITableViewController`), perform a segue when the initial view controller loads.